# How do I account for NULL being passed as parameters into my program?

Tags: c

I'm trying to concatenate two strings. I'm receiving a segmentation fault when I pass in NULL to S1 and/or S2. I figured it had something to do with line 19 through debugging but I can't figure it out due to my inexperience.

```
char *string_nconcat(char *s1, char *s2, unsigned int n)
{
        char *p1 = s1, *p2 = s2;
        unsigned int L1 = 0, L2 = 0, c = 0;
        char *cstr, *dest;
        if (s1 == NULL)
                s1 = "";
        if (s2 == NULL)
                s2 = "";
        while (*p1 != 0)
                p1++, L1++;
        while (*p2 != 0)
                p2++; L2++;

        if (n >= L2)
                cstr = malloc((L1 + L2 + 1) * sizeof(char));
        else
                cstr = malloc((L1 + n + 1) * sizeof(char));
        p1 = s1, p2 = s2, dest = cstr;
        if (cstr == NULL)
                return (NULL);

        while (*p1 != '\0')
        {
                *dest = *p1;
                dest++;
                p1++;
        }
        while (*p2 != '\0' && c < n)
        {
                *dest = *p2;
                dest++;
                p2++;
                c++;
        }
        *dest = '\0';

        return (cstr);
}
```

Comment: can you copy the copy without the rows number kinda makes it hard for others to help you

Comment: You've copied the `NULL` into `p1` or `p2` before checking if `s1` or `s2` is `NULL`.

Comment: When `s1` is `NULL` then at `while (*p1 != 0)`, `p1` is also `NULL` (because you have `char *p1 = s1`) so you are dereferencing a `NULL` pointer.

Comment: atSpinkoo Removed, my apologies.
@user3386109 That worked! So would the reason for the segmentation fault because I set the empty string after I was trying to access null?

Comment: C is an [imperative language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperative_programming). Therefore it does things in the order that you specify.  The assignment `p1 = s1` is *before* the assignment `s1 = ""`. Therefore, if `s1` is initially NULL, then `p1` will be NULL and `s1` will be pointing to an empty string. When you check the condition `*p1 != 0`, you'll get a segmentation fault because you're dereferencing a NULL pointer.

Answer (score 2):

When you detect that you've been passed in a NULL, you set `s1` or `s2` to the empty string, but that doesn't change what `p1`/`p2` are pointing to, so when you try & use them later, they're still pointing at the NULL.

Answer (score 0):

Add `*p1 = s1, *p2 = s2;` after ssecond while